# UDP Datagram socket not receiving data

Tags: java, android, udp

I am trying to access UDP data from server on port 1050. I am not receiving data in emulator and phone too, Seems like there is no issue in code because i am not getting any error in catlog. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
        try {
        int port = 1050;
        DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(1050);
        dsocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        dsocket.setBroadcast(true);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

        while  (true) {
        dsocket.receive(packet);
        String  lText = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data is coming...."+lText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("UDP packet received", lText);
        packet.setLength(buffer.length);
        }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```